# Array wont work with small sentences

Tags: java, arrays, word-count, variable-length

If I change the text to two words the program wont output anything. Not a clue on how to fix this, thanks in advance.

```
public class test {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String text = "The cat sat on the mat!"; //Change the string to "Hello there!"
    int wordLengthCount [] = new int [20];
    String wordCountText = "";

    String sentence[] = text.split("[,\\-:\\?\\!\\ ]");

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++)
    {
        wordLengthCount[sentence[i].length()]++;
    }

    for(int wordLength=0; wordLength<sentence.length; wordLength++)
    {
        if (wordLengthCount[wordLength] != 0){
            wordCountText += wordLengthCount[wordLength] + " with length of " + wordLength + "\n";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(wordCountText);
 }
}
```

Comment: WFM, output two lines: "1 with length of 2" and "5 with length of 3", live proof here: http://ideone.com/cl4o5V

Comment: Try changing the string to "Hello there!" there will be no output. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over all `wordLengthCount`

*Quick fix:*

```
for (int wordLength = 0; wordLength < wordLengthCount.length; wordLength++) {
    if (wordLengthCount[wordLength] != 0) {
        wordCountText += wordLengthCount[wordLength] + " with length of " + wordLength + "\n";
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/LGrczJ)